# Loading text in card with video attachment

Tags: google-mirror-api

I noticed that some other glassware , cnn one, has a "Loading" text under the video icon when buffering a video attached to a card.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an artifact of the way they're attaching video to their timeline cards. They are using video streaming.

This may be the best option if you already have video on a publicly accessible URL. To stream a video, specify the url in the [`menuItems.payload` field](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline#menuItems.payload). POSTing a timeline item with streaming video looks something like this:

```
POST /mirror/v1/timeline HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {auth token}
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 42

{ 
  "text": "Hello world",
    "menuItems": [{
      "action": "PLAY_VIDEO",
      "payload":"http://example.com/kitten-on-skateboard.mp4"
    }]
}
```

You can learn more about this in the [documentation for attaching video](https://developers.google.com/glass/timeline#attaching_video).

Comment: In my case i'm using Content-Type: video/mp4. Is this the issue?

Comment: Your content type is probably correct. It's a difference of implementation. If you use streaming, like CNN, you'd give the API a URL and a content type video/vnd.google-glass.stream-url. If you're sending the bytes, your content type is appropriate (and the loading message will not appear)

Comment: Jenny is it possible on C#, there is no attribute called Content-Type in TimeLineItem

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the updated API. You can see some .NET examples for usage here: https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline